# nested loop comparing ints in an array

Tags: c, arrays, compare

this is what I have. it is skipping over the zero. how can I fix that? I'm trying to count the number of times the numbers are duplicated.

```
void hit_rate(int a, int cmset[])
{
    int i, j, k=0;
    for(i=0;i<a;i++){
        for(j=i;j<a;j++){
            if((cmset[i] == cmset[j])){
                k++;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n",k);
        k=0;
    }
}

cmset      k **now** prints  
  4          2       
  6          1        
  0          3       
  0          2       
  0          1       
  1          1       
  2          1       
  4          1
```

Comment: `for(j=0;j<=1;j++)` is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While counting duplicates,
e.g. `arr[5] = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3};`
start with

```
i = 0; // first loop
j = i; //2nd loop
```

comapre `arr[i] == arr[j]; //condition`
By this what happens if you have tested arr[0] with all i = 1..4;
in next iteration, you have need not to check a[1] with arr[0], because it's already done (or checked).
increase the counter(when duplication matches). once it ends the end of the array reset counter. and print it.
I hope it helps. Still confused then I will provide you sample code.

Answer (score 3):

Should be `for(j=0;`**`j<a`**`;j++)`